# How can I include unity3d projects in android ones?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm trying to make an android application which includes two different projects created and exported from Uniy3d, one is a simple interactive 3d environment while the other is an AR application based on Vuforia's extension. I tried many tutorials [in unity Forum](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/71607-Integrating-Unity-and-Eclipse) and [vuforia too](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/extending-unity-android-activity-and-adding-custom-views-eclipse) but it doesn't seem to work... maybe because it's outdated since you can just export the unity project to eclipse in the last releases.

Do you have any idea on how I can possibly do this ?? Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity3D 3.5.7 and blow will generate apk directly, you can try Unity4 and it will generate an android project which can be import into eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I already did that but the problem is that I can only make a call for unity project from another project if the apk is already installed : I use this code for that 
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
     Intent intent = pm
       .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.test.moteur");
     startActivity(intent);
     Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
       "Chargement en cours", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
     t.show();

Comment: So I have to install each module separatly and reinstall it each time I change it ... any solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to create the whole application in Unity3D since it's possible to have a good User interface with it and not divide it into parts....